# Why is my C program slower than the Haskell equivalent?

Tags: c, gmp

I decided to compare the performance of the standard strict tail-recursive version of the Fibonacci program in Haskell to one written in C, using GMP to allow comparisons where the result is to big to fit in a word (in Haskell I use the multi-precision `Integer` type).  I'm going to omit the Haskell program, because this is a question about C and GMP.  The C implementation is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>

void fib(unsigned int n){
    mpz_t a, b, t;

    mpz_init_set_ui(a, 0);
    mpz_init_set_ui(b, 1);
    mpz_init(t);
    for(; n > 1; n --){
        mpz_add(t, a, b);
        mpz_set(a, b);
        mpz_set(b, t);
    }
    //mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, b);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    unsigned long n, f;
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: fibc <number>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fib(atol(argv[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that I commented out the line that outputs the value, which was taking about a second (I left this behavior in the Haskell version).

The results are:

```
time ./fibhs 1000000
./fibhs 1000000  5.77s user 0.05s system 99% cpu 5.831 total

time ./fibc 1000000
./fibc 1000000  11.19s user 0.00s system 100% cpu 11.194 total
```

I figure I must be using GMP wrong.  Can anyone see any performance improvement possibilities in the C code?

Comment: Well: it does 3 function calls per loop. Maybe Haskell inlines them, or compiles them into linear code?

Comment: Did you compile the C code in a C++ compiler with exceptions enabled?  Did you compile the C code with optimizations?  Which flags?

Comment: Also, Haskell has a pretty awesome optimizer especially with built-in "simple" types like "Integer".  I'd expect It made code completely different.

Comment: I compiled it initially as `gcc fib.c -o fibc -L$LIBDIR -lgmp`, and then with -O3, which shaved less than a second off the running time.

Comment: I'm aware that Haskell's optimizer is awesome, and this might explain why quants people are so fond of Haskell :-).

 I'm just wondering if it's possible to tune the C code to get performance approaching the Haskell code?

Comment: How about maintaining `mpz_t*` for `a, b, t` so the two `mpz_set()` could be simplified into pointer assignments?

Comment: @timrau that made all the difference :-p
`./fibc 1000000  4.45s user 0.00s system 100% cpu 4.447 total`

Comment: @jjm: How does my code compare on your machine? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b437abf8688e7b69

Comment: @MooingDuck slightly better than with pointer exchange: .
`/fibc 1000000  3.62s user 0.00s system 100% cpu 3.624 total`.  I'm utterly baffled by what you're up to there though, care to explain?

Comment: @jjm: It's basically the same idea as the pointer thing, but doing two iterations per loop (which is why the ending is so weird, if they wanted an odd count, we have to do one addition extra, and the result is in the other variable).  If it's confusing, step through with a debugger and watch a and b in action.  I actually suspect the `_mpz_realloc` is the big difference though.  Telling it to grab a ton of memory at the beginning so it doesn't have to keep grabbing new memory, coping the data, then releasing the old memory.

Comment: Actually my confusion was mostly related to not noticing that it's C++ ;-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play ping-pong. You have two variables a and b and a temporary t. You add and put the result into t, then you copy b to a and t to b. Instead alternate between adding b to a and adding a to b. The final result is either in a or b, depending on whether n is odd or even.

Comment: @timrau got there first.